# How do i determine if mongodb is returning empty results

Tags: mongodb, api, mean-stack, mean

I designed an API to fetch users from my mongodb in MEAN stack using express and I need to determine if mongodb is returning an empty array. Below is my code:

```
router.get('/user/:name', function (req, res) {
  users
    .find({ name: { $regex: '.*' + req.params.name + '.*' } })
    .exec(function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      } else if (user === null) {
        console.log('user not found')
      } else {
        res.json(user)
        console.log('user found')
      }
    })
})
```

I tried querying such that the results would be empty but the console still logs **"user found."** Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `find`. This function always returns an array, if no user is found it returns an empty array, which is never equal to `null`.

If you use the function `findOne` then a document or `null` will be returned.

Check the length of the result instead:

```
} else if (user.length === 0) {
```

If you want to retrieve only one document, you can use findOne:

```
users.findOne({name: {$regex: ".*"+req.params.name+".*"}}).exec( // ...
```

In that case your checks do not need to be changed.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Apparently i cannot use findOne becuase there can be many users with the same name. Thanks again!!!